# Vary height of hero image with browser window size

Tags: javascript, css, browser, screen

I am trying to achieve an effect which can be seen on the https://lexus.com.au website where

- no matter what the browser screen height (desktop or laptop etc) the hero image and the cta bar always fill the browser screen.
- The height of the hero image varies as the browser height changes.
- The image also centres on the main content as the screen changes.
- The CTA bar at the bottom of the screen always remains the same height and location.

Is this done with JS using window.InnerHeight or some other method?

Comment: You can set the width of your image to 100vw and the height to auto if you want it to always take up the full width of the screen. To keep an element in the same location use the fixed property.

Comment: If are you trying to set full height of the window then you should be use this simple trick `.lx-hero-image__info{height: calc(100vh - 146px);}`   Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR: 
Is this done with JS using window.InnerHeight or some other method? **No**

There are 2 reasons that contribute to this and while there are likely more, these are the ones I can see without rebuilding what was done just to give you the answer.

1. They use the  `background-position: % %` to position the image.

   > The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the vertical. The top left corner is 0% 0%. The right bottom corner is 100% 100%. If you only specify one value, the other value will be 50%. Default value is: 0% 0%

   https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp
   This is what gives the image that look of squeezing under the top banner.
2. Then these were done to position the element itself within the above div.  `background-size: cover; display: table;`  https://mattboldt.com/kicking-ass-with-display-table/

It's important to understand that throughout this the reason for it taking up the full width is simple; width was set to 100%. That is actually the easiest part of the whole effort. However combining the above elements to get the correct effect will take some playing with on a codepen. That being said what I've given you is what you need to know to succeed.

Links below are good links to get you started on fully understanding how to complete this task.